# Going from Javascript to C++. I have teacher and student objects, and I want to display if they are teachers or students. How should I do this?

Tags: c++, class, methods

This may be too general of a question, but basically whenever I try to find an answer for something that would work from a Javascript approach, the answer heavily implies that you wouldn't do it that way.  So I'm asking very generally.

For example, I could chuck both in one array if it were Javascript and then use "instance of" to check what they are, but [they say you'd never want to do that in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27159791/cs-version-of-extends-anotherclass).  Or in Javascript, you could simply check .is_teacher, and if it weren't defined for the object student, it would be treated as false.  But trying to check is_teacher on a student class doesn't work in C++ if you haven't declared it, it won't compile.

So it seems like I have a fundamental problem of my approach.  Is it just best not to create separate classes until really necessary?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 6):

`instanceof` is a code smell, even in ECMAScript. You should be using Polymorphism for this. There is the [*Replace Conditional with Polymorphism Refactoring*](https://www.refactoring.com/catalog/replaceConditionalWithPolymorphism.html), which allows to replace a conditional which checks for something "type-like" with polymorphism. In your case, you are not just checking on something "type-like", you are *literally* checking the type.

In an object-oriented language, there is *never* a need to check the type. Never. It can always be replaced by polymorphism. Smalltalk is the existence proof of this: Smalltalk has no `if`, no conditionals of any kind, no loops. *All* it has is polymorphism.

Here is (roughly) what that would look like in ECMAScript:

```
class Teacher {
    toString() { return "Teacher"; }
}

class Student {
    toString() { return "Student"; }
}

const arr = [new Student(), new Teacher()]
arr.forEach(console.log);
// Student
// Teacher
```

As you can see, the objects know by themselves whether they are teachers or students. There is no need to check what they are, because they already know it, and the right method will be called automatically.

The code would look very much the same in C++:

```
#include <string>
#include <shared_ptr>
#include <iostream>

class Person {
public:
  virtual ~Person() {}
  virtual std::string toString() = 0;
};

class Teacher: public Person {
public:
  std::string toString() { return "Teacher"; }
};


class Student: public Person {
public:
  std::string toString() { return "Student"; }
};


int main() {
    std::shared_ptr<Person> people[] = { std::make_shared<Student>(), std::make_shared<Teacher>() };

    for (auto& person : people) {
        std::cout << person->toString() << "\n";
    }
}
```

The idea is that the *language* takes care of figuring out for you whether a person is a student or a teacher. Whether that uses overloading of virtual functions, or overloading of operators, or argument-based overloading doesn't *really* matter. Especially in C++, there are multiple different ways of achieving this. For example, overloading `std::cout`'s `operator <<`, using the new C++11 `std::to_string` feature, creating an overloaded `to_string` virtual member function, overloading the `std::string` cast operator, and so on and so forth.

Comment: I'm guessing some stuff needs to be made virtual explicitly. Like I said, absolutely no C++ knowledge :-D

Answer (score 2):

You say you want to "display" whether they are teachers or students. That sounds very much as if you'd want to have a routine that outputs information (or just formats the information so that the caller can output it). Usually you'd implement this through *polymorphism*, i.e. as an overridden method in the teacher and student classes. Is there any reason why you wouldn't want this?